# Entity Framework Core doesn't load on the package

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

I have a project on Gitlab which works fine. I have to reinstall the windows and visual studio 2022 and clone it again. but after clonning , none of packages loads find and I get error

[image]

the project works fine, everybody on team is working with it. I have installed dotnet runtime 5 and 6 and also sdk 5 and 6

the project has been created by .Netcore 5
I can not uninstall or install a package also
what could be the problem

Comment: "he project has been created by .Netcore 5"  -Have you tried downgrading the packages, also the nuget packages. Maybe you have chosen packages for .Net6 and not .Net5.

Comment: @Schecher_1: I have cloned it from gitlab. I haven't choose anything

Comment: Has it always worked before? And you really did NOT change anything?

Comment: ps, take for erros no pictures instead the text, so that you can see everything and copy. (use the code block for this)

Comment: @Schecher_1: it is working fine right now on my laptop, but not on my newly installed widnows Pc

Comment: may you add the whole error code in your question. So that I can take a closer look at everything.

Comment: @Schecher_1: it is on the picture, the packages have tirangle which means they are noe loaded, and the error message on the left side of picture it shows timeout for loading nuget

Comment: In fact, I think it's really strange. If you really can't reinstall packages or something else. I would actually (unfortunately) reinstall VS2022 again.

Comment: Happend to me also because I  had spaces in  solution folder name. Maybe that's the case

Comment: Spaces, special characters, etc. are generally very dangerous for files. Rather take a "-" or best "_"

Comment: @nnmmss first post errors as *text* , not images. Images can't be copied, googled or tested. Second, what you posted is a network error. This has nothing to do with Visual Studio. You can't restore packages from NuGet if you can't even connect to NuGet. Finally, .NET 5 reached End Of Life in May. The current Long-Term-Support version is .NET 6, supported until 2024.

Comment: @Schecher_1 reinstalling Visual Studio won't fix networking problems. The image says the machine can't connect to NuGet.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, the error message is like: Failed to download package xxxxxx from "source link" the http request to "Get source link" has timed out after 100000ms.

I think the timeout issue is more related to the network. You could try using a VPN or setting up your own NuGet repository locally should be a good suggestion.

Steps to set local source:

1. Create a local folder, such as, "D:\LocalServer"
2. Add this path to the package source, under Tools->Options->NuGet Package Manager->Package Sources
   [image]
3. Download the packages you need from nuget.org to this folder, then you can install the packages to your project from loacl source.